# Drag and Drop with WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have two `ListBox` in WPF application. One is the source second is the destination. I took the help from the article http://dotnetslackers.com/ADO_NET/re-191632_Generic_WPF_Drag_and_Drop_Adorner.aspx

Now I have managed to perform the drag and drop.

Now I have one feature to implement in which if we drop any item over an existing one, it will replace the existing item with the current dragged item.

Please guide.

Comment: Can't you just remove any matching item from the list?

Comment: @kenny I actually remove the old item as soon as its dropped on the destination listbox. Its just like moving one item to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [Gong Solutions Drag/Drop for WPF](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/), the guide it uses an adorner and should be able to show you how to remove the old item and add a new one, as @kenny suggested.

Comment: I will use the Gong Framework link provided by you and try to implement it and then get back to you. Thanks for your reply!