# WPF dealing with files in a listBox

Tags: c#, wpf, video, listbox, mp4

I intend to create a .mp4 Listbox from which I can play an .mp4 of my choice.
I've already created the .mp4 player(by drag&drop) and I'm dealing with trouble with how to deal with the listBox.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath.ToString());
            if (result == FORMS.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo f in dr.GetFiles())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

This only enables me to get all the .mp4 files(from selected folder) to be shown in the listBox,
How do I manage to drag objects from the listBox into the .mp4 player(which is already drag and drop enabled).

Comment: I think you're looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859797/drag-and-drop-with-wpf-listbox

Comment: "WPF dealing with files in a listBox" is a very misleading title according to OP actual issue. Same for tags. ATM, suggested edit queue is full. Just to point out I'm willing to make the title more specific, and correct the tags that are out of place, it's just that I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the  [DragDrop.DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx) method.

Example:

```
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
        <ListBoxItem>X</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Y</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Z</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

And in code

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     ListBox listbox = sender as ListBox;
     DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox, listbox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.None);
}
```

Could be that in your mp4 player you'll need to implement more than just enable drag&Drop (like extract dragged item and play it ...)

You can find more information about on [MSDN Drag and Drop Overview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

:) Thanks alot, that really helps! You were right about the .mp4 player, he does need to identify the drag onto him but I just couldn't figure out how. I did manage to write the code to play an .mp4 by dragging an .mp4 directly from your computer (desktop for example) and here's the code for that:

```
        private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = (string)((DataObject)e.Data).GetFileDropList()[0];
        mediaElement1.Source =new Uri(filename);
        mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mediaElement1.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mediaElement1.Volume = (double)slider_vol.Value;
        mediaElement1.Play();
    }
```

There are other add-ons to that code but they don't really matter.
What function from Drag and Drop should I use on the "Play" button for the player? and how do I get the filename to actually handle that file? Thanks!